# How to configure apache for angular 2

Tags: apache, angular

I need to configure virtual host for angular2. I have tried following this article

```
https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Web+Development/9781783983582/2/ch02lvl1sec15/Configuring+Apache+for+Angular
```

According to this i need to setup virtual host like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
  # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell me what should be the path to app as my app is running on default angular 2 port that is 4200.
Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: You say that your app is running on the default Angular 2 port 4200 that is when using a local server for development? When you want to use this on a production server you would build the Angular2 app depending on your build, if you're using angular-cli you would use `ng build --prod` and upload the contents of the dist folder to your apache server document root for that virtual host.

Comment: @JJB i have done that and app is running on ip:4200, but i want to use virtual hosts for eg: www.testapp.com and redirect this to my angular app using apache

Comment: You use the contents inside the `dist` folder just like any other website you upload that content and serve that via apache and make sure all .html files load via index.html. What you are talking about is the local test server that is created when running Angular in a test environment you won't be using NodeJS to serve the Angular2 app you will be using your Apache server. The `ng serve` is just for serving the local development server it has nothing to do with Angular. You are using angular-cli right?

Comment: Just to be sure... your project IS in fact angular-cli or some sort of webpack??

Answer (score 34):

**angular-cli build**

On your local development environment run `ng build --prod` in your project root.

This will create a folder called `dist`, you want to place all the files and folders from within `dist` to your Apache root directory on your server.

Setup apache to serve routes to index.html. You have two methods you can use, either edit your virtual host or use .htaccess in your website root directory.

---

**Option 1: Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Option 2: .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @J J B  Can you tell me what that index.html file will have.Can you show me example of index.html

Comment: The index that is in your dist folder.  Can you please confirm your build system you are using. Webpack or SystemJS? Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: Please tell me how the config will change if i would need a VirtualDirectory with an alias inside angular app folder. For example /api will point to /angularappfolder/service/ ?

Comment: Please add your apache config file so I understand what you already have.

Comment: @JJB, I am new to this mod_rewrite configuration. Just wanted to confirm my understanding of the conditions and rules you have mentioned. 1. The first two conditions will mean, `If the url is pointing to a file or a directory then render it and exit` 2. The first rewrite rule will  `come in action if the first two conditions didn't match and will simply close the condition checking for the above two conditions` (what is `-` between `^` and  `L` ?) 3. The second rewrite rule says `If it is none of the above, then redirect to index.html `

Comment: @AshishRanjan
Yes that is correct and `^` means match anything `-` means do nothing

Comment: Option 1: need a change for apache2.4
add `Require all granted` in `Directory` directive.

Comment: I just tried this Option 2, and it is working super fine, but I tried this on a single page application, do you know will it work if we have multiple routes ?

Comment: @Lint Yes this will work for Angular apps with multiple routes because the app will receive all routes and Angular will translate the routes on the client-side.