# Merge two separate Angular project to one URL on apache server

Tags: angular, apache, amazon-web-services, angular-routing, amazon-ecs

I have two different projects in Angular (one is in version 6, other in 7) and each project has own routing module.

I must merge them into one domain url. To be clear I must do in that way:

*my-domain.com* -> go to first app.

*my-domain.com/app2/* --> go to second app and also first app should have some button to redirect to second one.

If is easier to do *my-domain.com* can redirect for *my-domain.com/app1*.

That projects were already configured in AWS cloud with docker and apache. Right now I have two different domain and load balancer point to separate ECS.

I've tried to do some apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my-domain.com

  LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so

  ####
  configuration for OIDC plugin
  ###

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-app/www/

  Alias / "/var/www/html/my-app/www/"
    <Directory /var/www/html/my-app/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^manifest.json /base/manifest.json [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/* /index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    Alias /app2 "/var/www/html/my-app/www/app2/"
    <Directory /var/www/html/my-app/www/app2/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^manifest.json /base/manifest.json [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/* /index.html [L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But unfortunately is not working as expected.

Second tired was from that medium article: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Since new angular has ability to create sub-project:

```
ng generate application app1 –-routing
ng generate application app2 –-routing
```

Since it was easy app, like in the tutorial, was working as expected but when migrate my apps I had an error for each modules:

```
ERROR in ./projects/app1/src/app/modules/contact-page-module/contact-page.module.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: my-app/projects/app1/src/app/modules/contact-page-module/contact-page.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:752:23)
at plugin.done.then (my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Already read that is problem with multiple modules in sub apps.

```
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: '../modules/home-page-module/home-page.module#HomePageModule',
  }
```

I couldn't find any solutions on the darkest side of internet and also didn't figure out by myself.

Of course I can merge the code from two applications into one but I'd love to keep separate it and repository each, though.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that issue with Apache configuration. Maybe in some day you need that solutions.

The main problem was Angular routing. When url is pointed to domain.com/some_route_path, Apache thinks that user want to see files from folder named some_route_path but there index.html is missing so Apache show us page with nothing.

Let me explain more details, I used default Apache config so my main folder to put all generated files from Angular is */usr/local/apache2/htdocs*. After put url domain.com in browser, apache point direct to htdocs and looking for index file. But after click on menu, routing redirect to domain.com/some_route_path and after refresh browser, apache by default looking folder some_route_path in htdocs so is bad behaviour for us thus to working angular application we need to inject special config e.x. [How to configure apache for angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348210/how-to-configure-apache-for-angular-2)

After applied mentioned configuration angular application starting working fine. But in my case I'd like to work with two independent angular apps.

- domain.com -> one apps with itself routing.
- domain.com/second-app -> second angular app.

the latter app should have own routing so if user put url domain.com/second-app/some_other_router_page, that case should be handle by index.html in folder second-app. With configuration from the above link, the first app is working fine, but when go to second app, the whole routing is taking by the first one thus second is not working properly.

I figure out that configuration and now both apps working with theirs routing.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-domain

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
         <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted

              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} second-app
              RewriteRule second-app/(.*)$ /second-app/index.html?path=$1 [L]

              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/second-app/ [NC]
              RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [L]
             </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In my case I had some business case to do it. But in testing env is good to test couple of angular applications in one apache server. It can reduce cost of machines.

I can prepare github project if someone would like to see real life example with docker apache.